# submitting task to ProcessPoolExecutor does not call method

Tags: python-3.x, concurrent.futures

My python app has a ProcessPoolExecutor, and I'm submitting class methods as tasks to the executor.

```py
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor

# In other module file
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
    
    def run(self, secondsToSleep):
        print("start running...")
        time.sleep(secondsToSleep)


# In main file
def main():
    obj = MyClass()

    with ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
        future = executor.submit(obj.run, (10, ))
        executor.shutdown(wait=True)
```

The "start running..." is never called. If I grep python3 processes, I can see multiple processes were spawned.

I changed print to file logging but there were no change.

Comment: Why are you passing 10 in a tuple? That part's not working. Try instead just: `future = executor.submit(obj.run, 10)`. Also, you never call `main()` so what you posted would never run anything.

Comment: I tried ```future = executor.submit(obj.run, 10)``` and called the main method actually but no difference.

Comment: It's working for me (Ubuntu 20.04LTS) in python 3.9